# Notify user when marking the older question as the duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Sometimes people mark a older question as the duplicate of a newer one, while of course it should be marked the other way around. One example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng#comment19860344_2686855).

Could it be a solution to perform a date validation between the two questions (and notify the user if necessary) when a duplicate is being marked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no rule that the newer question should be marked as duplicate of the older question. In fact, the real guidance and expectation is that you leave the *better* question, or the question with the better *answer*, open. Sometimes, that means the new question is the duplicate. Other times, that means the older question is the duplicate.

In other cases, the new question receives an answer where the old question had none. A question cannot be closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question, unless you're here on Meta, so it makes sense to close the older question in that scenario.

In your specific example, one user feels that the newer question is the better question. That comment is roughly three years old now and the suggested action has not been taken, so it's reasonable to think that so far, the community has not agreed. (Indeed, at first glance, it looks like the current closure in your example is correct. The open question seems to be more general to me.)

Comment: [Apparently I was not the only one who didn't know that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686855/is-there-a-javascript-function-that-can-pad-a-string-to-get-to-a-determined-leng#comment23440384_2686855). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Found some more information on this [here: *"Usually a recent question will be closed as a duplicate of an older question. But this isn't an absolute rule."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/262970) in case people are interested.